# http status 500:internal server error in eclipse,tomcat,mysql

Tags: java, internal-server-error, tomcat9, navicat

i had started tomcat in eclipse and mysql in navicat and run the code the web page was successful but when i request to server it ran into an error called "htttp status 500".Where is the problem in code ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.AI.Dao.AdminDaoimpl.adminLogin(AdminDaoimpl.java:24)
    com.AI.Servlet.AdminServlet.doPost(AdminServlet.java:76)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: At the line 24 of AdminDaoimpl.java you access object being `null`

Comment: at line 24:ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from admin_registration where emailid=? and password=?");    and  initialized as PreparedStatement ps=null; this gives an error NullPointerException. Then what it should be initialized as?